# How to set scaling, fit, resolution of plots in Rmarkdown files and Rmarkdown html documents?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, visualization

I have created a plot taken as reference from below website:

[Plot Web Reference](http://www.rebeccabarter.com/blog/2019-08-05_base_r_to_tidyverse_pt2/)

**Issue**

When I plot the same in my Rmarkdown source editor or create html document from it then it's fit & resolution appears nothing like that in the website.

How can I replicate it as it is?

**Setting Parameters**

I have used `dpi = 300`, `fig.height = 15` and doesn't matter what `out.width` i take it doesn't help.

**Below is the snapshot comparison of website Vs my rmarkdown editor.**

`Left` is from original website; `Right` is from my Rmarkdown editor

[image]

**Temp Solution below - that have worked only on this chart**

Turns out setting `fig.width=7` restricted the plot from scaling and worked as in the website.

But in other similar charts when the x-axis scales to higher values then this problem appears on those which doesn't get fixed using this approach.

So how can I re-scale my axis if the x-axis values increases a lot?

**Code is available on website but also posting below:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

gapminder <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swcarpentry/r-novice-gapminder/gh-pages/_episodes_rmd/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv")

gapminder <- gapminder %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
```

```
gapminder_life_exp_diff  <- gapminder %>% 
                              filter(year %in% c(1952,2007)) %>% 
                              
                              # filter(country %in% c("India","Vietnam")) %>% 
                              
                              arrange(country, year) %>% 
                              
                              group_by(country) %>% 
                              
                              mutate(lifeExp_diff = lifeExp[2] - lifeExp[1],
                                     max_pop = max(pop)) %>% 
                              
                              ungroup() %>% 
                              
                              arrange(lifeExp_diff) %>% 
                              
                              filter(max_pop > 30000000) %>% 
                              
                              mutate(country = droplevels(country)) %>% 
                              select(country, year, continent, lifeExp, lifeExp_diff)
```

```
# Dumbell plot

gapminder_life_exp_diff %>% 
  mutate(country = fct_inorder(country)) %>% 
  
  group_by(country) %>% 
  
  mutate(max_lifeExp = max(lifeExp),
         min_lifeExp = min(lifeExp)) %>% 
  
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  # plotting begins
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = min_lifeExp, xend = max_lifeExp,
                   y = country, yend = country,
                   col = continent), alpha = 0.5, size = 7) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x = lifeExp, y = country, col = continent), size = 8) +
  
  geom_text(aes(x = min_lifeExp + 0.25, y = country,
                label = paste(country, round(min_lifeExp))),
            col = "grey50", hjust = "right") +
  
  geom_text(aes(x = max_lifeExp - 0.35, y = country,
                label = round(max_lifeExp)),
            col = "grey50", hjust = "left") +
  
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20,85)) +
  
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Pastel2") +
  
  labs(title = "Change in Life Expectancy",
       subtitle = "Between years 1952 and 2007",
       col = "Continent") +
  
  # background & theme settings
  theme_classic() +
  
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank()
        )
```